# What is the best way of listing technical skills in a resume

Tags: resume

So far, I've been listing the skills mentioning technologies related to the field:

- Networking: subnetting, DHCP, DNS, IPv4, DLP, IDS/IPS, NAC.
- Programming: C++, Java, Python, Perl.

However, recently, I have seen a couple of resumes in which the writer explains briefly his experience in each field. For instance:

- Networking: designing of large networks and set up of security measures like DLP, IDS/IPS and NAC systems.
- Programming: C++, Java and some exposure to scripting languages like Python and Perl.

So now I'm wondering, from the point of view of a recruiter, whether one way is preferred above the other or it's irrelevant the way I'm listing technical skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most CVs are scanned and fed into a system that picks up on the keywords. So I would recommend to trigger as many references keywords related to the field you want to be in.

From a reading perspective I would recommend to put the related skills against the block of work experience area (again just the keywords). This allows the person reading it to get a clearer picture of your experience relative to the current time.

For example:

```
Job1: 'Title' - Company - Duration.
Skills: Java, C++, etc
Details:
```

The details section can go into more in relation to your job.

This helps because it gives a clearer picture to the interviewer to your skills. For example if you only put "10 years Java experience" and failed to mention you hadn't touched it in the last 3 years then you are going to get a negative response from the interviewer.

Comment: As an interviewer, this format is always very helpful. I often find the first questions when scanning a resume to what skills did you use at x job/project, and it allows me to get a better idea of your expertise. Seeing a 3 month contract job with x technology would give me a different idea than a 3 year full time job working with x. It gives me a better idea where to start digging in, and help avoid the inevitable "its been a few years since I've used x".

Comment: This format seems good, but I cannot use it because of my lack of experience.

Answer (score 3):

Well you want your CV to have as much information as possible but make it digestable in a very short space of time over a small area.  That way anyone scanning can pick up everything they need to know quickly but re-read, study and reference to find out much more information once you've caught their eye.

What I tend to do in order not to waste space with lists (as they take up valuable vertical space), is just describe my job and put the technologies or key points in bold so a scan of my CV says "*Company X...2011-2014...Software Engineer...Java, Hibernate, XML, SQL*", ok information digested in 20 seconds, I have their interest, a re-read then reads

> ### Company X - *2011-2014*
>
> *Software Engineer*
>
> Working on a fantastic system writen in **Java** that does magical
>   things using **Hibernate** with some nifty **XML** and **SQL** tricks.
>   Working to deadlines with huge customer bases. I enjoyed this part and
>   this part but not so much this part.

This means you can also expand on how you used technologies which fit the narrative and are easily referable in interviews.

Answer (score 1):

We like the skills, like you've been listing them at the top.  The details on how you used them should be detailed in the job section.  It's important for hiring managers to know where you did what.

Example. Networking. "Installed and configured Microsoft servers, updated software and supported business unit users" Is vastly different if you did this at a 10 person law firm vs. a 10,000 person technology company.  That's why employment specific details are needed in the body of the résumé